# Como autenticar usuário via AD ou via Banco SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, iis, active-directory

O usuário tem que acessar via **autenticação Active Director**y quando estiver nas dependências da Empresa e quando estiver fora da Empresa o acesso será via **consulta de login e senha** em uma base de dados SQL Server.
No caso de acesso via **AD** a configuração do web.config deverá ser a seguinte:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

No código da página `Index` eu faria algo assim para identificar o usuário (não sei se é o suficiente) ?

```
var usuario = User.Identity.Name;
    if(usuario != ""){
        //Acesso liberado
    }else{
         return RedirectToAction("Tela_de_Login");
    }
```

E para uma autenticação via consulta **SQL Server** eu faria assim:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Usuario/Login" timeout="2800"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

Dúvida:

Vai existir algum conflito caso eu implemente essas duas configurações do Web.config ?

Como fazer para o sistema saber se o usuário está acessando dentro do domínio da Empresa ou acessando via Web, ou seja, de fora do domínio da Empresa ?

Obs.: Sei que deve ser feita algumas configurações no IIS também.

Comment: @AdrianSUV: Um mesmo usuário teria duas formas diferentes de autenticação, armazenadas em ambientes distintos? Isto faz sentido? // Porque não autentica sempre contra o AD, mesmo o usuário estando *fora*? // O acesso externo não poderia ser por VPN?

Comment: Não, o acesso externo deve ser através de qualquer computador via browser.

Comment: O sistema na empresa onde eu trabalho funciona assim. Você tem que utilizar o forms authentication, mas no `Global.asax` você coloca um evento no fim da request, para verificar se a response é um 302 (ou seja, usuário não autorizado/autenticado, normalmente redirecionaria para a página de login), mas daí você muda o código http de resposta para 401 caso detecte que o client está dentro da rede (assim forçando o browser a negociar as credencias do windows para autenticação). No entanto, eu nunca utilizaria o usuário do AD para logar no BD, mas aí é de cada empresa.

Comment: Entendi @Alisson, até agora a sua sugestão foi o mais próximo do que estou procurando e acredito sim que vai funcionar obrigado pela resposta, porém no seu comentário não existe o _usuário do AD_ o que existe é o usuário que está logado na máquina e pode ser qualquer usuário, exemplo _joao.silva_ do _Comercial_ ou _ana.maria_ do _marketing_ é isso mesmo que a gente tá falando ?

Comment: Normalmente em uma rede corporativa o usuário que está logado na máquina tem que *ter um usuário no AD*, ou seja, existe sim um usuário do AD. Nessa sua aplicação, somente usuários do AD poderão se autenticar, ou um usuário externo (ex: um cliente/fornecedor) poderá se autenticar com usuário e senha, sem precisar ter usuário no AD?

Comment: Correto @Alisson ! , foi apenas uma má interpretação por minha parte sobre o usuário AD, assim que eu implementar darei um retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia implementar usando os 2 tipos de logins AD e Banco de Dados.

Na tela de login o sistema "busca" o usuário no AD:

- Caso ele exista, faz o procedimento de validar o usuário (verificar se usuário e senha são válidos).
- Caso não exista, vai direto no BD e faz a validação.

Veja se esse link pode te ajudar:
https://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/